# Dirichlet problem for Laplace equation in $\Omega=\left(\overline{B\left(0,a\right)}\right)^{c}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm having troubles with the proof of the following theorem: let $\Omega=\left(\overline{B\left(0,a\right)}\right)^{c}$ and $U\in \mathbb{R},U>0$, then there exists a unique function $\psi\in C^{2}\left(\Omega\right)\cap C\left(\bar{\Omega}\right)$ solution of the following problem:
$$\begin{cases} \Delta \psi=0, &\mbox{in }\Omega \\
\psi=0, &\mbox{in }\partial\Omega \end{cases}$$
plus an asymptotic constraint on $\psi$ given by: $\psi\left(x,y\right)\sim Uy$. In polar coordinates: 
$$\begin{cases} \Delta \psi\left(r,\theta\right)=0, &\mbox{for }r>a,\theta\in\left[0,2\pi\right] \\
\psi=0, &\mbox{for }\theta\in\left[0,2\pi\right] \end{cases}$$
with the asymptotic constraint given by $\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\psi\left(r,\theta\right)}{r}=U\sin\theta$.

The solution of this problem should be: 
$$ \psi\left(r,\theta\right)=c\log\left(\frac{r}{a}\right)+\left(1-\frac{a^2}{r^2}\right) Ur\sin\theta $$
where $c\in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant, which can be determined by imposing the following condition: 
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\intop_{\partial B\left(0,a\right)}\vec{u}\cdot d\vec{s}=-c $$
where $\vec{u}=-\left(\nabla \psi\right)^{\perp}$ and $c\in \mathbb{R}$ a given number.
 Now, my question is: can I apply the separation of variables in order to solve the given problem? If yes, how can I conclude from the (formal) series
$$\psi\left(r,\theta\right)=c_1+c_2\log r+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(a_{n}r^{n}+b_{n}r^{-n}\right)\left(\sin\left(n\theta\right)+\cos\left(n\theta\right)\right)$$ 
obtained by applying separation of variables, the solution written before? Also, how can I justify rigorously the obtained formula and finally conclude that the solution is unique?

Comment: I'm not sure the solution of either problem is unique, depending on what you mean by the asymptotic constraint: $c$ is undetermined by the equations you have.

Comment: I've edited the text, now should be a little bit more clear. By asymptotic constraint I mean that we require the function to satisfy the given condition at infinty.